# python How to plot scatter and regression line with more than 127 or 128?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a simple scatter and also overlay a simple regression. All the x,y points plot in a scatter form, as expected, no matter what. Great. My problem is that if N is >127 then all the (x,y) points are plotted, but the regression line does not extend from the min(x) to the max(x). The regression line should extend all the way from the left side (to min(x)) all the way to the max(x). What is going on here and how can I fix it?

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
N=128
x=np.random.rand(N)
y=np.random.rand(N) 
fit = np.polyfit(x,y,1) 
fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)
ya=fit_fn(x)
ax1.plot(x,y, 'bo',x, ya,'-k')
```

I did notice that if I change the last line to

```
ax1.plot(x,y, 'bo',x, ya,'-ko')
```

then all the points plot, but this is not what i want since this gives me a scatter plot for x,ya instead of a line.

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to get what's the issue here, the line is still there (because of the `-` but also are all the points overlapped over the line (because of `ko`). If you want a proper scatter plot, try `plt.scatter` although that's what `plt.plot` defaults to, I imagine, when you leave out the line designation.

Answer (score 1):

I get it now. I'm not quite sure why that happens like that, but there's a way around it. Does this produce the same result? (see mine bellow)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

#distribute N random points in interval [0,1>
N=300
x=np.random.rand(N)
y=np.random.rand(N)

#get fit information
fit = np.polyfit(x,y,1) 
fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)

#extend fitted line interval to make sure you
#get min and max on x axis
current = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 0.01)
current_fit = np.polyval(fit_fn, current)

#you can extend it even, default is color blue
future = np.arange(min(x)-0.5, max(x)+0.5, 0.01)
future_fit = np.polyval(fit_fn, future)

#plot
ax1.plot(x,y, 'bo')
ax1.plot(current, current_fit, "-ko")
ax1.plot(future, future_fit)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this did work. Thanks. It would be nice to know how to get this right though.

Comment: @user2015487 You might be confusing the way `random` works. `random` just spews out numbers between 0 and 1 and it is possible that you sometimes don't get numbers higher than some limit (because they're random it happens). But on your graph I can clearly see numbers extending past the end of your line, but even the line looks weird. In my example. I don't know. I used `np.arange(bot, top, step)` which doesn't spew out random numbers. It takes `bot` and then adds `step`, and repeats until it reaches `top`. Since you have a function, all I do is calculate values in those points and plot them.